# Cache base url #{request.contextPath} in a variable to use multiple times on page & included pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to cache `#{request.contextPath}` into a variable so that it could used multiple times within a page. Previously while I was working with Mojarra 2.1.3, I could use `ui:param` for this purpose & that would cache the expression value for entire page  & across all the included pages in the current page. But [it doesn't work with Myfaces(see issue)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3595) reason being `<ui:param>` should be direct child of `<ui:include>` or `<ui:define>` to work.

I have been suggested to use `c:set` but I want to avoid working with JSTL tags  as far as possible. What is recommended for my use case ?

Comment: Why would you want to cache such a simple expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<c:set>`. It doesn't harm anything in this particular case.

---

> *but I want to avoid working with JSTL tags as far as possible.*

It look like that you don't **understand** why and when JSTL tags should (not) be used and thus overgeneralizes the usage of all JSTL tags in JSF as "bad" for ever. You shouldn't think that. Carefully read this answer to get enlightened: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/3343681#3343681)